# Creating JSON Array in PostgreSQL by reading comma separated values

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

I have 2 tables in my PostgreSQL database.

Table 1 has the `Product_Details`:

| Product_Name | Allowed_Transaction_Modes | Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Salary_Account | ATM,NEFT,UPI,GPay | Premium |
| Savings_Account | ATM,UPI, GPay | Silver |

The second table contains the description of these allowed transaction modes - `Transaction_Models`:

| Allowed_Trans_Modes | Description |
| --- | --- |
| NEFT | National Electronic Funds Transfer |
| UPI | Unified Payments Interface |
| GPay | Google Pay |
| ATM | Automated teller machine |

I need to create the following JSON output by using a select query

```json
[
  {
    "Product Name": "Salary Account",
    "Allowed_Transaction_Modes": [
      {
        "code": "ATM",
        "description": "Automated teller machine"
      },
      {
        "code": "NEFT",
        "description": "National Electronic Funds Transfer"
      },
      {
        "code": "UPI",
        "description": "Unified Payments Interface"
      },
      {
        "code": "GPay",
        "description": "Google Pay"
      }
    ],
    "Category": "Premium"
  },
  {
    "Product Name": "Salary Account",
    "Allowed_Transaction_Modes": [
      {
        "code": "ATM",
        "description": "Automated teller machine"
      },
      {
        "code": "UPI",
        "description": "Unified Payments Interface"
      },
      {
        "code": "GPay",
        "description": "Google Pay"
      }
    ],
    "Category": "Silver"
  }
]
```

Tried writing a few queries from Google but they do not work.

Comment: Why not save the Allowed_Transaction_Modes as json objects? That will save you from all the processing you're attempting to do to try and build json objects from the array.

Comment: Thanks Peter, This is an old legacy code that I am reading and using the CQRS pattern to push JSON payloads onto to an ES Index. These are read only tables

Answer (score 0):

First, You need to convert the string to an array then join it with **Allowed_Trans_Modes**. After that, you can use `jsonb_agg` to create array of JSON

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=9fe63888b22eb4b7f62bdc0778837bd8)

```sql
with data as (
  select
    pd."Product_Name",
    pd."Category",
    jsonb_agg(
      jsonb_build_object(
        'code', 
        tm."Allowed_Trans_Modes", 
        'description',
        tm."Description"
      )
    ) as agg
  from
    "Product_Details" pd,
    "Transaction_Modesl" tm
  where
    tm."Allowed_Trans_Modes" = any(string_to_array(pd."Allowed_Transaction_Modes", ','))
  group by
    1, 2)
select
  jsonb_agg(
    jsonb_build_object(
      'Product Name',
      "Product_Name",
      'Allowed_Transaction_Modes',
      agg,
      'Category',
      "Category"
    )
  )
from
  data
```